# Scale Space Between Multiple Objects

Tags: objects, transforms

If I have multiple objects selected can I use scaling to make the objects closer together (without rescaling the objects)?

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3413/is-it-possible-to-move-parts-of-a-model-along-the-selected-normals

Answer (score 38):

Yes, enable the pivot-point-align option.

This transforms the center points only.

One way to think of this is as a ferris-wheel - where each gondola stays in place, but you can rotate their locations.

**Scale:**
[image: scale]

**Rotate:** *Even though you didn't ask about this, it helps to understand how the feature works.*
[image: rotate]

Comment: That is awesome! I never realized this feature existed! +1.

Comment: I've just had a look in the Manual but there seems to be nothing about this useful little feature.

Comment: Elegant and effective combination of simple tools is pure joy.

Comment: Wait, did they change the name of that button? I swear the popup calls it "object centers only". Grawr, computer not handy.

Comment: This does not work in edit mode, just a reminder.

Answer (score 11):

As answered by @[ideasman42](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1310/228), pivot point align option is a really awesome transformation tool. That coupled with Proportional Editing (Object Mode with Constant Falloff) the following transformations can be easily achieved.

### Initial state of the objects

1. Enable Pivot Point Align (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>).
2. Enable Proportional Editing (<kbd>O</kbd>).
3. Choose Constant Falloff (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> until constant falloff is displayed).

[image: Enable Pivot Point Align, Proportional Editing with Constant Falloff]

### Left most object selected and scaled

Start scaling the objects and move the mouse while adjusting the proportional inflience area by scrolling the mouse wheel

[image: Start scaling the objects]

### Middle object selected and scaled

In this case, the objects are proportionally scaled about the middle object.

[image: Another way of scaling the same set of objects]

Answer (score 3):

For version 3.1:

1. Open the 3D view side panel for current tool and select `Affect only` | `Locations`.
2. Select `Active Element` as the pivot point.
3. Use the scale tool.

[image]

[Documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/tools/tool_settings.html) for further details.