# Can I model in a set of co-ordinates local to an object?

Tags: modeling, coordinates

I am using Blender for architecture. I would like to be able to take an inclined plane (representing a roof, for example) and then place and manipulate simple objects onto it - just as simply as I can play around with them on the z=0 plane.

In a similar way, when I am in this local co-ordinate system (which I realise might not be catered for in Blender) I would like to be able to select top view (for example) and be looking at the plane from the opposite direction to its normal.

Is any of this possible ?

Comment: For entering ortho views for selected faces see - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15045/how-do-i-align-the-viewport-to-a-face-normal. For editing objects along another axes other than global see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3413/is-it-possible-to-move-parts-of-a-model-along-the-selected-normals.

Comment: In addition to what mrZak said, you can use custom transform from a selected face or edge

Comment: https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/transform_orientations.html#custom-orientations