# How to extrude a face parallel to another?

Tags: modeling

I'm wondering if there is a fonction to extrude down the faces selected to put them on the red dotted line, while maintening them parallel to the vertical edge?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extrude inwards without leaving faces?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50780/how-to-extrude-inwards-without-leaving-faces)

Comment: Here is how to set transformations from "Global" to "Normals" http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3413/is-it-possible-to-move-parts-of-a-model-along-the-selected-normals

Comment: I've just read your link and tried it but it doesn't work or I'm doing something wrong. If I extrude the faces selected the reference of the axis aren't the vertical plane so it can't be parallel to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### The fast, inaccurate way

1. Select one of the upper edges and the lower edge, which you want to connect.
2. Subdivide <kbd>W</kbd> > <kbd>S</kbd>
3. Use the edge / vertice slide by pressing <kbd>G</kbd> > <kbd>G</kbd>
4. Enable the **Even** checkbox in the edge slide operation settings.
5. If necessary enable the **Flipped** checkbox in the edge slide operation settings.
6. Adjust the Factor slider estimating the slide position closest to the upper vertex.
7. Merge the upper vertices.

[image: edge slide]

#### The slow, accurate way

1. Delete the face, which you want to split with the edge (loop).
2. Select the edge, which you want your new edge to be parallel to.
3. Go into **Normal** transform orientation mode, then (in the Properties Panel under Transform) press the <kbd>+</kbd> icon. [image: add transform] This will add the orientation of the edge as a possible transformation orientation.
4. Place a new vertex by subdividing the lower edge.
5. Snap the 3D cursor to the upper vertex, from which you want the edge loop to start.
6. Enable *2D Cursor* as *Pivot Point*.
7. Select the vertex on the lower edge and scale it to 0 (with the 2D cursor as a pivot point). Limit the scale operation to the X and Z axis. Select the transform orientation of the edge, which we added earlier.
8. Make the new faces.

[image: custom transform orientation]

Comment: Sorry, the gif is a bit too fast. I have modified step 3 and 7 explaning how I added the Transform Orientation of the selected edge. Is it more clear now?

Comment: It's cristal clear now!