# precisely moving faces in different directions

Tags: modeling

Here is a picture to help show what I mean

Thanks to anyone who helps :D[image]

Answer (score 1):

Click <kbd>G</kbd> to grab or translate the face, which you've selected and type the certain distance you want the face to go. You can use the <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd> and <kbd>Z</kbd> keys to lock the movement to a certain axis.[image]

Comment: To piggy back this comment, you can also hold down shift while dragging to make a more precise selection.

Answer (score 1):

[Is it possible to move parts of a model along the selected normals?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3413/is-it-possible-to-move-parts-of-a-model-along-the-selected-normals)

TL;dr:
You may also move the faces along the normals.
To do this just change the Transform Orientation.

[image]

Doing so aligns the Z axis with the Normals of the selected faces.
After pressing G for Grab Press <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>z</kbd> to move along the normals (Pressing once moves them along the Global Z-Axis)
EDIT: Formatting

Comment: This would be the better way, if the model is not correctly aligned to the global axis'.

Comment: so tell me, did it work out as planned ?