# What does the button next to the Pivot Point button do?

Tags: interface, workflow, transforms

In the 3D view port's header, what does the button next to the *Pivot Point* button do? The button in question has a shortcut of <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>,</kbd>. It is in the red square in the picture below. 
[image]

What is it use for and how is it used?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That button  is the *manipulate center points* option, which allows you to manipulate the origins of objects without affecting the rotation and scale of the objects themselves.

For example, if I scale these objects without it enabled, they are stretched. With it enabled, only the origins are moved (only affecting object location):

[image]

Note that with only one object selected, enabling this option will cause scaling or rotating the object to do nothing.

Comment: The icon makes sense once you know what it does.

Comment: @Neil Wow.. I just noticed that my example gif sort of matches the icon :P That was a complete accident..

Answer (score 4):

It is the pivot point align option, it allows to rotated or scale selected objects relative to the selected pivot point.

In this animated gif the pivot point is set to *3D-Cursor*.

[image]

Related:

- [Scale Space Between Multiple Objects](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1308/scale-space-between-multiple-objects/1310#1310)