# How come I can't rotate?

Tags: armature, transforms

I am making a model and in object mode, you can't rotate, scale, mirror, etc a mesh. The only way to do it is to got to edit mode, select and then rotate. That worked for me until I made a armature and you can't rotate it in pose mode!

Comment: What do you mean you can't rotate? the handels aren't there? have you tried the hotkeys? or it just will not rotate when told?

Comment: Is the armature in *Rest pose*? (*Properties panel > Object data > Skeleton*)

Comment: The handels are there but it wont rotate anything

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It sounds like you have *Use Transform Pivot Point Align* (perhaps more intuitively known as "transform only locations") enabled. You can find this setting in:

- The *Options* dropdown in the *Tool Settings* bar, by default found in the top right of the 3D view.
- The *Pivot Point* pie menu, which is bound to <kbd>.</kbd> (period) by default.

[image: gif showing different rotation settings]

This setting makes it so transforms will only affect the *[origins](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.0/scene_layout/object/origin.html#object-origin)* of objects, rather than the objects themselves. This is only really very useful when you have multiple objects/bones selected.

Also see [What does the button next to the Pivot Point button do?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/12303/599)

---

In 2.7, this setting was called *Manipulate origins* and bound to (<kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>,</kbd>) as well as a button the header of the 3D View:

[image: image showing manipulate origins icon in the header]

Comment: In Blender 3.4 there is no arrow with 3 small boxes anymore. Unable to rotate it

Comment: @Coliban Sorry about the delay, I've updated my answer