# Why won't anything in my scene rotate when I press"r", or "r" "r", or go to the rotation tool and click it?

Tags: rigging

Look at the image below please! It's weird. When I press r or rr on the keyboard or drag the rotation tool it doesn't rotate. The rotation you can see is not locked! This bone wouldn't rotate, or any other bones. It was fbx imported, but I've imported it before and it didn't work. Nothing will rotate in the scene.[image]

Comment: Do you have [*manipulate origins* enabled in the header?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/23213/599)

Comment: @gandalf3 Where is the header?

Comment: @gandalf3 And where can I find manipulate origins? Thank you

Comment: The [*Header*](https://www.blender.org/manual/interface/window_system/headers.html) is the bar normally at the bottom of an [*Area*](https://www.blender.org/manual/interface/window_system/introduction.html#the-default-scene). Did the [answser](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23216/599) I linked above help?

Answer (score 1):

In the header where you can choose visualization mode(Rendered/Wireframe/Solid...) you have a button with "..." and two arrows below, that mode is causing the problem.

[image: Manipulate Center Points]