# Scale and Rotate Stopped Working

Tags: 3d-view, transforms

I am using Blender 2.80 beta. In *Object Mode* **Scaling** and **Rotating** objects stopped working.

How do I enable rotating and scaling again?

The button that is referenced in Blender 2.7x does not exist in Blender 2.80.
The odd thing is if I create a new model everything works fine...it just stopped working on my original model and still isnt working.

???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How come I can't rotate?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23213/how-come-i-cant-rotate)

Answer (score 29):

In the latest release the tool options header is hidden by default. However, the same options can be accessed from the Property panel.

From the panel, go to the **Active Tool and Workspace settings** tab > **Options** header > **Transform** > **Affect Only** and then uncheck all (Origins; Locations; Parents).

[image: Properties panel location]

Answer (score 7):

If you can't scale/ rotate in Blender 2.8a you can solve this problem by clicking on the right top header "Options" field and **unchecking** all

[image: options]

Answer (score 2):

Probably you have activated the *Only Origins* option. You can find it in the end of pivot point menu.