# Scale & Rotate function not working in object mode

Tags: transforms

I've been making a donut and coffee cup via Blender GURU 2.8. However now back in object mode my scale and rotate is suddenly not working. I can move items but scale and rotate seemed to have locked?
Can't seem to fix it.

---

Many Thanks for this ... however there is no option to click off the only origins point in drop down menu, please see photo. Would it be anywhere else?
[image]

Comment: As well as the answer below  look out for locked transforms in the 3d View > Properties region > Item tab.

Comment: Possibly answered here - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129170/scale-and-rotate-stopped-working-2-8

Answer (score 1):

You probably enabled *Transform Only Origins* in the pivot point menu.
Just disable it, and everything is going to work as before :).

*Click Only Origins to disable the function*
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Blender 3.6 you can find it here:

[image]