# Automatic Node Distribution and Alignment

Tags: interface, node-editor

The Unreal Engine has the ability to align and distribute nodes:

[image]

Does Blender's node editor have such a feature hidden somewhere?

Comment: You can scale and rotate multiple nodes like you would object origins, but it's a little limited. There are some addons which provide this kind of functionality though (e.g. Node Wrangler, which is bundled with blender)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Default transforms:

You can rotate and scale multiple nodes as you can objects with [*Manipulate origins* enabled](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/12303/599):

[image]

You can use the usual tricks, e.g. press <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> (or <kbd>Y</kbd>) <kbd>0</kbd> to align nodes along a particular axis. Note that the "origins" of all nodes are at the top left.

## Node wrangler

This [addon](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Nodes/Node_Wrangler) comes bundled with blender by default, but you'll have to enable it. It comes packed with all kinds of workflow accelerating functions and shortcuts; press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> in the node editor to get a menu of all of them.

One such function (<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>=</kbd>) aligns the selected nodes:

[image]

## NodeArrange

An experimental script [recently featured](http://www.blendernation.com/2015/11/03/development-cleaning-up-node-trees/) which completely rearranges an entire node tree:

[image]