# How to scale a group of objects the right way?

Tags: modeling

I have made a car out of different objects and I want it to stay that way but when I scale the car this happens :(

How to make the car bigger or smaller without combining all the objects into one mesh?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I guess you have the pivot point type set to 'individual origins'. Try to change it to '3D cursor' (http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5519/setting-the-pivot-point-of-an-object). Now set the cursor to the center (Shift+C) and then scale.

Comment: You have `manipulate origins` enabled

Comment: As @NᴏᴠɪᴄᴇIɴDɪsɢᴜɪsᴇ said, it looks like you have [*Manipulate Origins*](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/12303/599) enabled. Disable it by pressing `Ctrl ,` (comma). Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/105/599

Comment: Why don't you want to join the objects?