# How do I move all children objects away from parent empty (by scaling the empty) but NOT scale the children?

Tags: parent

I have a bunch of boolean modifiers on a cube. I want to move them all off the cube by just scaling the empty they are parented to. But, I don't want the child objects scaled. Is there a way to do this (non-python)?

I am happy to use drivers or other techniques to achieve the same result: namely moving the booleans off the cube in a direction as if they were scaled. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Possibly related: [Scale Space Between Multiple Objects](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1308/78972)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is the same problem i had, and you are using version 2.81, try this:
[image: Maybe the solution]

Comment: No idea where you got that popup form. And I'm not sure why affect only parents would work-- as these are children, not parents that are moving.

Comment: @chippwalters You can also find those settings in the *Tool* tab of the `N` panel (under *Options >Transform*). I'm not sure about *Affect Only Parents*, but *Affect Only Origins* sounds like what you're looking for.